# Auto-Wrap huge C++ libs to C for import in Swift / Go

Tags: swift, go

Let's say i have a huge lib in C++ (with tons of dependencies, it needs about 3h for a full build under GCC). I want to build upon that lib but don't want to do so in C++ but rather in a more productive language. How can i actually bridge or wrap that extern lib package so i can access it in another language and program on top of it?

Languages considered:

- Swift
- Go

What i found is, that both languages do provide auto bridging or wrapping for C libs and code (I don't actually know whats the difference between wrapping / bridging). So, if i have some c code, i can just throw it in the same Swift or Go project and can use it with a simple import in my project.

This doesn't work in both languages for C++ code however. So i googled how to transform C++ libs to C code or generate autowrappers. I found the following:

1. swig.org - auto wrapper for C++ libs
2. Comeau C++ compiler - automatically transfers C++ to C code
3. LLVM - should be able to take *any* input and transform it to *any* output that LLVM is capable of.

Question:

1. Is it even in the realms of usable / realistic / managable to build
   on top of such a huge lib in other languages like Swift / Go, if
   using auto wrapping or auto bridging?
2. What of the 3 listed libs / programs / frameworks works best for the process of C++ -> C (because Swift and Go both provide C auto
   wrapping).
3. Are there better alternatives than what i considered so far?
4. Would it be better to just "stick with C++" as using any other tools to do the wrapping / bridging process would be far to much
   work to equal out the benefit of using a more productive language
   like Swift / Go?

Thanks:)

Disclaimer: There is also the possibility to manually wrap a C++ lib in C but that would take an unbearable amount of work for such a huge lib.

Comment: Unless the library was designed ground-up with language interoperability in mind this is likely to be a huge if not impossible undertaking. The main challenges are going to be object life-time management (compatibility with your host language GC) and turning every argument into some plain C representation. Of course, it's possible that the library is huge but its API is small in which case you are in luck.

Comment: SWIG is extremely powerful and can wrap quite complex systems and is certainly capable of working with large libraries.  It won't automagically do it, you'll need to tweak and tune your SWIG *.i files, but SWIG is a solid way to address this kind of thing as it gives you ways to define how the original language is wrapped and exposed to the the new calling language.

Comment: You might be interested in [cgogen](https://cgogen.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Q1: Is it realistic?

Not realistic, because any large complicated C++ interop is going to get too complicated.  Automatic tools are likely to fail and manual work is too hard.

Q2: What's best?

I don't know and given A1 it does not seem to matter.

Q3: Alternative?
Q4: Is C++ only the best alternative?

If you want to take advantage of existing C++ code from another language regardless of the language involved the best option in complex scenarios is to use a hybrid approach.

Most languages provide interop to C and not C++ due to non-standard C++ naming convention.  In other words, just about every language provides access to plain C-functions, but C++ is frequently not supported.

Since your library is complex, the best solution would be based on "Facade" pattern.  Create a new C-library and implement application specific logic that utilizes C++ library.  Try to design this library to be as thin as possible.  The goal is not to write all business logic, but to provide C-functions that hold on C++ objects and call C++ functions.  The GO-level language code would then call this library to use C++ library underneath.  This approach differs from Q1 approach.  In Q1 you attempt to have one interop call on per C++ function or object's method.  In Facade you attempt to implement C++ usage scenarios that are unique to your application.

With Facade you reduce the scope of interop work, because you target your application scenarios.  At the same time you mitigate away from C++ complexity at GO language level.

For example, you need to read a temperature sensor using C++ library.

In C++ you'd have to do:

1. open file
2. read stream until you find SLIP terminator
3. read one "record"
4. close file

With facade you create a single function called "readTemperature(deviceFileName)" and that C function executes 4 calls at once.

That's a fake example, just to show the point.

With facade you might want to hide original C++ objects and at this point it becomes a small layer.  The goal here is to stay focused and balance your application needs with generalization to support your application.

Interestingly enough Facade approach is a way to improve interop performance.  Interop in just about every language is more expensive than normal operations due to need to marshal from langauage runtime environment and keep it protected.  Lots of interop calls slow down application (we are talking about millions here).  For example, having 10 interop calls combined into 1 improves performance, because amount of itnerop operations is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful wrapping a large (although perhaps not "huge") C++ library (hundreds of header files) in Swift using a relatively simple process. You directly link your project to the library. The only thing you have to wrap are any new functions that you write (to be invoked in Swift) that actually use the library (in the C++ wrapper file). The verbose stuff can be left in the wrapper file, mostly without any modification. There is a simple little tutorial which helped me: https://www.swiftprogrammer.info/swift_call_cpp.html

(FYI, there is one step he omitted:  Set your library search paths in Build Settings => Search Paths => Library Search Paths (both Debug and Release) )